# XML style for Latex including Persian characters with some preferences

Tags: xml, xepersian, persian

I am using the `listings` package to include some `XML` code in my document. Currently, I am using the following style:

```
\lstset{   
basicstyle=\ttfamily,   
columns=fullflexible,  
showstringspaces=false,   
commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape }

\lstdefinelanguage{XML} {   
morestring=[b]",   
morestring=[s]{>}{<},  
morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},   
stringstyle=\color{black},  
identifierstyle=\color{darkblue},   
keywordstyle=\color{cyan},  
morekeywords={xmlns,version,type} }
```

I have two main problems:

1- if the size of an element is bigger than the size of the line, the rest of the element text does not go to the next line and continues in the same line and the text goes to the margin!

2- It does not support Persian characters. I mean for example if I have an attribute like

```
Root="گوشی"
```

it does not write the Persian word.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to TeX.SX. You can have a look at the [starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/32374) to make yourself familiar with the site. You may notice I've edited your post a little bit. Code is formatted by indenting it by four spaces, rather than the `>` at the beginning of the line. It would also be a great help if you could include a full [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/32374) beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Adding `breaklines = true` to the `lstset` will automatically break the lines at the margins. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1875803/2449192

Comment: @darthbith Thanks dear friend. the first problem is solved. How about Persian characters? I know that xepersian package is for supporting Persian. how can I add the settings related to using xepersian package to the lstset?